# Can't resolve 'devextreme/animation/frame' while using devextreme with react

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, devextreme

I am trying to use devextreme datagrid table in react. However, importing it gives this error:

```
./node_modules/devextreme-react/core/templates-renderer.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'devextreme/animation/frame'
```

I am importing its components as follow:

```
import DataGrid, {
Column,
Selection,
Paging,
Summary,
TotalItem} from 'devextreme-react/data-grid';
```

I installed it refering to the instructions on the documentation:

```
npm install devextreme-react@21.2 --save --save-exact
```

I can't really know why this module is not found.

Help can be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the same issue by first installing only devextreme package with npm and after that devextreme-react.